# How to stop calling ng-click when dynamic data not in id value on same button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<a id="cli_id"
   ng-controller="EservlogsModalCtrl"
   ng-click="foo()">
   Create New Log
</a>
```

I am triggering a click event using jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cli_id').click(function (){
        var customer = $('#4c609cf1bbb6c5080865df9cfc1fb649_mylogs_details_customer').val();
        if (customer == '')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }); 
});
```

I had expected that the ng-click would not fire when I `return false`.  But I can see that it does fire.

How can I avoid the ng-click from firing in this case?

Comment: dont use `ng-click` and `jquery` on same button. use the angular controller to manipulate the logic. what exactly you need?

Comment: I want to click on button first of all read my java script for checking and then return true or false if false return then ng-click should be stop working .

Comment: Please not the commentary provided by @Sravan & please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score 1):

First of all **DONT USE JQUERY WITH ANGULAR**, instead  angular controller to manipulate the logic.

This can be done in few ways, here is one of them.

If you have a field with `id` `4c609cf1bbb6c5080865df9cfc1fb649_mylogs_details_customer` then use **`ng-model`** on it.

**Example using ng-model:**

```
<input type="text" id="4c609cf1bbb6c5080865df9cfc1fb649_mylogs_details_customer" ng-model="customer_details">
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.openlogsEservModal = function(param1,param2,param3,param4)
    {

        if ($scope.customer_details; == '') {
            // return false / Do nothing;
        }
        else
        {
         // write your logic here
        }
    }
});
```

If it is dynamic and **`if you cannot use ng-model`**,

In the method, `openlogsEservModal` check the condition you want to check using `angular.element` and do your logic.

Here is the controller, you can use like this,

**Example without using ng-model:**:**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.openlogsEservModal = function(param1,param2,param3,param4)
    {
     var customer = angular.element('#4c609cf1bbb6c5080865df9cfc1fb649_mylogs_details_customer').val();
        if (customer == '') {
            // return false / Do nothing;
        }
        else
        {
         // write your logic here
        }
    }
});
```